# append a div to the body for each clicked link in the list

Tags: jquery, html, each

I have a `rightsidebar` like in facebook with a list of friends , I want to append a new chatbox when  clicking on each of this friends list, the first time i click it appends a div to the body but when I click on the other links nothing happens!!!

Here is a portion of my html  -

```js
var chatBox = $('<div>',{'class' : 'PBchatBoxContainer'});
$('.PBChatFriendsList li a').each(function(index, el){
    $(this).on('click',function(){
     $('body').append(chatBox);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="PBChatFriendsContainer clearfix">
    <ul class="PBChatFriendsList">
         <li>
             <a href="#">
                 <div class="chatFriendContainer">
                     <div class="friendChatPhoto">
                         <img src="img/chat_user_photo.jpg" alt="tarek hatem">
                     </div>
                     <div class="chatFriendFullName">
                         <span>John Diggle</span>
                     </div>
                     <div class="chatFriendStatus">
                         <div class="userConDispositif">web</div>
                         <i class="online-icon"></i>
                     </div>                                           
                 </div>
             </a>
         </li><!--endof list element-->                                    
    </u>
</div>
```

Comment: You don't need `.each()` to bind click handler, jQuery does it for you.

Comment: You need to set `chatBox` inside click handler, otherwise `append()` will just 'move' the same box to the same point, btw, the each loop is useless here

Comment: i see why it's useless but please tell me how to calculate the position of each box to put them at the bottom of the page next to each others

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a new 'chatbox' each time the link is clicked, in your example `.append` will do nothing after the first click, as the element is already attached to the DOM.

You can also drop the `.each` as jQuery already attaches event handlers to all matching selectors.

```js
$(function () {
  
  $('.PBChatFriendsList li a').on('click', function () {
    var chatBox = $('<div>',{'class' : 'PBchatBoxContainer'});

    $('body').append(chatBox);
  });

});
```

```css
.PBchatBoxContainer {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

.PBchatBoxContainer::after {
    content: 'chatbox'
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="PBChatFriendsContainer clearfix">
    <ul class="PBChatFriendsList">
         <li>
             <a href="#">
                 <div class="chatFriendContainer">
                     <div class="friendChatPhoto">
                         <img src="img/chat_user_photo.jpg" alt="tarek hatem">
                     </div>
                     <div class="chatFriendFullName">
                         <span>John Diggle</span>
                     </div>
                     <div class="chatFriendStatus">
                         <div class="userConDispositif">web</div>
                         <i class="online-icon"></i>
                     </div>                                           
                 </div>
             </a>
         </li><!--endof list element-->                                    
    </u>
</div>
```

Comment: but why you put the css :: pseudo selector ?

Comment: @user1583331 That's just so you can see the chatbox being added in the snippet - you can obviously ignore this for your solution!

Comment: okey , i need to figure out how to put each opened chatbox at the bottom of page , i mean how to calculate the left position for each one ?

Comment: I guess you're trying to emulate FaceBook's chat boxes? You could always just use `float: left;`? Updated my answer with an example.

Comment: Please see the updated code snippet - the boxes should be displaying next to each other.

Comment: this technique doesn't suits my need, the chaboxs must be at the bottom of the page like in fb so i have to position them by manipulating the right value since the first chabox shows up at the bottom right

Comment: i wa wrong but basicaly your technique might be the better approach to make it , i'm working on it and i'll post the final result when i'll finish thank's